# Django choices list conversion

Tags: django

I want to use a list I have created from a static json file as a menu option on my web page. This does not work when I makemigrations. I believe the issue is that choices is expecting the two field format, rather than the list I have created. How do I convert this?

Makemigrations error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
from django.db import models                                                                                    #Generic for models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User                                                                     #Required for dynamic user information
from django.forms import ModelForm                                                                              #Custom form
#from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField                                                           #Required to support json for lists - Obsolete?
#from django.db.models import JSONField                                                                         #Required to support json for lists - Also obsolete?
from jsonfield import JSONField
import json

#json static data imports
data = open('orchestration/static/router_models.json').read()                                                   #opens the json file and saves the raw inventory contents
inventory = json.loads(data)                                                                                    #converts to a json structure

#Constructor for the list of router models
ROUTER_MODELS = []                                                                                              #List of router models
for routers in inventory["router_models"]:
    print(routers["model"])
    ROUTER_MODELS.append(routers["model"])

#Unique order. Top of heirachy tree
class Order(models.Model):

    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)#, null=True, blank=True)                         #Unique name of order
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Project_created_by', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)        #Person who created the order
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                                        #Date/Time order was created

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_name

#For CE router definition. Required for all orders.
class Ce_Base(models.Model):
    '''
    #Hardware models of router
    ROUTER_MODELS = (
            ('CISCO2901', 'CISCO2901'),
            ('ISR4331', 'ISR4331'),
            ('CISCO1921', 'CISCO1921'),
            ('ISR4351', 'ISR4351'),
            ('ISR4451', 'ISR4451'),
            ('ISR4231', 'ISR4231'),
            ('ISR4431', 'ISR4431'),
            ('ISR4461', 'ISR4461'),
            )
    '''
    #Available regions in which the router can reside.
    REGION = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'),
            ('5', '5'),
            ('6', '6'),
            ('7', '7'),
            )

    #Properties of CE Base
    ce_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                               #Hostname of router i.e. PENNER-DCNCE-01. Always required.
    new = models.BooleanField()                                                                 #Whether the router currently exists on the network. Always required.
    location = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)                                          #Address of the POP site/rack location. Required if new.
    router_model = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=ROUTER_MODELS)           #Hardware model of the router i.e ISR4351. Required if new.
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=REGION)                        #Region in which the router resides. Always required.

    #Foreign key to tie CE Base to an order
    order_reference = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)             #Order reference

    #Dynamic lists for port allocation
#    atm_ports = django.db.models.JSONField                                                     #ATM ports which are used for ADSL connectivity
#    async_ports = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #ASYNC ports used for console access
    l3_interfaces = JSONField(null=True)                                                        #Layer 3 interfaces
#    l2_interfaces = django.db.models.JSONField                                                 #Layer 2 interfaces

    #Dynamic lists for LAN vlan allocation
#    vrf_18_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 18 Infinera
#    vrf_19_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 19 Nokia
#    vrf_21_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 21 BMS
#    vrf_22_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 22 Ciena
#    vrf_23_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 23 Legacy
#    vrf_25_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 25 DIA
#    vrf_26_vlan = django.db.models.JSONField                                                   #VRF 26 ONAT
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this as below, but open to better suggestions.

```
#Constructor for the list of router models
ROUTER_MODELS = []                                                                                              #List of router models
for routers in inventory["router_models"]:
    print(routers["model"])
    ROUTER_LIST = []
    ROUTER_LIST.append(routers["model"])
    ROUTER_LIST.append(routers["model"])
    ROUTER_MODELS.append(ROUTER_LIST)
```

Comment: I knew this thing, that there is a problem in the loop, but  haven't answer that because of fear of downvoting :)